# samsung galaxy tab API for detection of video out

Tags: android, video, galaxy, galaxy-tab

Is there an SDK API add-on for Galaxy Tab that allows detection of video out? As far as I know there is no Android API for this and that vendors are providing their own, but I havent found any API extension from Samsung.